# How to check UUID using regular expressions?

Tags: node.js, uuid, jsonschema

In order to make validation over a api, i'm send companyId as UUID like: `71158c1a-56fd-4dd4-8e7f-fb95711a41de`

To have this validation I used `jsonschema` with the following patterns (test all 3 of them):

- `/^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$`
- `/^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$/gi`
- `[\w]{8}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{12}`

jsonschema:

```
  companyId: {
      type: "string",
      default: "",
      title: "The companyId Schema",
      pattern: "/^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$",
      examples: ["71158c1a-56fd-4dd4-8e7f-fb95711a41de"],
    },
```

For some reason the validation returned me errors:

```
    path: Ä 'companyId' Å,
    property: 'instance.companyId',
    message: 'does not match pattern "/ÜÄ0-9a-fA-FÅä8åÖÖb-Ä0-9a-fA-FÅä4åÖÖb-Ä0-9a-fA-FÅä4åÖÖb-Ä0-9a-fA-FÅä4åÖÖb-Ä0-9a-fA-FÅä12å$"',
    schema: ä
      type: 'string',
      default: '',
      title: 'The companyId Schema',
      pattern: '/ÜÄ0-9a-fA-FÅä8åÖb-Ä0-9a-fA-FÅä4åÖb-Ä0-9a-fA-FÅä4åÖb-Ä0-9a-fA-FÅä4åÖb-Ä0-9a-fA-FÅä12å$',
      examples: ÄArrayÅ
    å,
    instance: 'aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee',
    name: 'pattern',
    argument: '/ÜÄ0-9a-fA-FÅä8åÖb-Ä0-9a-fA-FÅä4åÖb-Ä0-9a-fA-FÅä4åÖb-Ä0-9a-fA-FÅä4åÖb-Ä0-9a-fA-FÅä12å$',
    stack: 'instance.companyId does not match pattern "/ÜÄ0-9a-fA-FÅä8åÖÖb-Ä0-9a-fA-FÅä4åÖÖb-Ä0-9a-fA-FÅä4åÖÖb-Ä0-9a-fA-FÅä4åÖÖb-Ä0-9a-fA-FÅä12å$"'
  å,
```

Also im getting these cyrillic letters, maybe this is the reason?

Comment: I see a lot of gibberish chars in the code you posted eg: `pattern: '/ÜÄ0-9a-fA-FÅä8åÖ` -> (`ÜÄ`) did you anything in the parentheses?

Comment: no, please see the attached jsonschema validation

Comment: You should look at whether you are performing utf8-decoding properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of JSON Schema supports the `uuid` format (you may need to explicitly turn on format validation in the implementation, as by default it is supposed to be annotation-only):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "type": "string",
  "format": "uuid",
}
```

Also, you have a stray `/` in your pattern before the `^` anchor, so your pattern will never match.